# T-SQL Regex range in XML method nodes()

Tags: sql-server, regex, xml, t-sql

I have a table T with two columns. Column A is a varchar column and Column B is a XML column.

Somewhere inside Column B there is always the following parent tag: `<Documents> ... </Documents>`. Inside there are some `<Document>...</Document>` children.

I would like to get a result set with two columns:

Column 1 should contain the same values of Column A;
Column 2 should contain the content of one `<Document>...</Document>` only.
Also, in column 2 there should only be `<Document>`s with attribute equal to 1, 2 or 3.

E.g. Starting table T:

```
Column A | Column B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc      | <Documents><Document ID="1">Doc Foo</Document><Document ID="4">Doc Bar</Document></Documents>
def      | <Documents><Document ID="2">Doc Foo2</Document><Document ID="3">Doc Bar2</Document></Documents>
```

Expected result:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
-------------------------------------
abc      |<Document ID="1">Doc Foo</Document>
def      |<Document ID="2">Doc Foo2</Document>
def      |<Document ID="3">Doc Bar2</Document>
```

I can get the expected result like this:

```
SELECT
     [Column A]     AS [Column 1]
    ,T2.c.query('.') AS [Column 2]
FROM T AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY T.nodes('*/Documents/Document[@ID="1" or @ID="2" or @ID="3"]') AS T2(c)
```

But when filter conditions are more complex it can get out of control without regex.
This does not work:

```
SELECT
     [Column A]      AS [Column 1]
    ,T2.c.query('.') AS [Column 2]
FROM T AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY T.nodes('*/Documents/Document[@ID="[1-3]"]') AS T2(c)
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Where does the filtering come into it? you say the Regex gets more complex, but 1-3 is hardly complex.#

Comment: Subquery; extract the `@ID` as a column and `WHERE` on it. XQuery and T-SQL each have their own strengths and weaknesses. (And no, the XQuery implementation in T-SQL supports nothing in the way of regexes, and constructing queries dynamically is possible but very clumsy and should really only be done if there's no other way for functionality or performance.)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what @JeroenMostert suggests, and if he's correct, then perhaps what you are after is:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('abc',CONVERT(xml,'<Documents><Document ID="1">Doc Foo</Document><Document ID="4">Doc Bar</Document></Documents>')),
                ('def',CONVERT(xml,'<Documents><Document ID="2">Doc Foo2</Document><Document ID="3">Doc Bar2</Document></Documents>')))V(Col1,Col2))
SELECT YT.Col1,
       Ds.D.query('.')
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY YT.Col2.nodes('Documents/Document') Ds(D)
WHERE Ds.D.value('@ID','int') IN (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter on the attribute to appear in a sequence of values:

```
Document[@ID = (1,2,3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. *XQuery* is based on the notion of sequences. So you need to check if the `@ID` attribute value is a member of the sequence.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID CHAR(3), xmldata XML);;
INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, xmldata)
VALUES
('abc', '<Documents><Document ID="1">Doc Foo</Document><Document ID="4">Doc Bar</Document></Documents>')
, ('def', '<Documents><Document ID="2">Doc Foo2</Document><Document ID="3">Doc Bar2</Document></Documents>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , c.query('.') AS [Column 2]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/Documents/Document[@ID=("1","2","3")]') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+-----+--------------------------------------+
| ID  |               Column 2               |
+-----+--------------------------------------+
| abc | <Document ID="1">Doc Foo</Document>  |
| def | <Document ID="2">Doc Foo2</Document> |
| def | <Document ID="3">Doc Bar2</Document> |
+-----+--------------------------------------+
```